# Angular 2 observable not giving my subscribers the latest data when data is added to observable

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

I have an angular 2 observable that many parts of my app are subscribing to but are not getting data.

Note: I have no build errors or console errors.

The subscribers only receive data on load in their component in the ngOnInit section.

**This is an example of the ngOnInit subscriber:**

```
 ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.service.getData$
      .takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
      .subscribe(data => {

         //This only gets hit on component load and not when the observables updated.
         console.log(data);
      });
  };
```

**This is my simple service:**

```
  private _testStream = new BehaviorSubject<any>(new myTestData);
  public getData$ = this._testStream.asObservable();

  updateObs(item): void {
    this._testStream .next(item);
  };
```

**This is my model being updated and pushed to the observable:**

```
export class myTestData { 
  listOfData: Array<Object> = [
    {
        id: "testA",
        visible: true
    },
    {
        id: "testB",
        visible: true
    }       
  ]
};
```

I want the subscribers to receive the new data when I push to the observable.
It seems the service updates the observable fine but the subscriber's aren't receiving the data.

Very strange.

Comment: It seems my service is not being adding as a provder in the correct place?

Answer (score 0):

The instance of the Service used by all the different components needs to be the same, so that means you cannot add it to the `providers` array of each component. Instead, add it to the `providers` array of the parent Module.